# Why does conda not use symlinks for duplicate dependencies?

Tags: package-management, python, symlink, datascience-anaconda

I wondered whether conda actually made duplicate files for certain dependencies shared by independent environments.

I installed two environments `env1` and `env2`. Then I installed the same module `cryptography` in both of them. Next I searched for the module's name in my system with `find` and found it in `miniconda3/envs/env1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/` as well as `miniconda3/envs/env2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/`.

Next I went through all directories from `site-packages` on and `ls -al`-ed for symlinks. I did not find any symlinks on the path to `cryptography`. Hence these must be actual copies of the same module and the same version of it.

Is this not very wasteful of disk space? Why does conda not use symlinks for cases like this? I would like to know the rationale behind this design as I suspect other environment managers handle things the same way?

Comment: what is "too broad" about it?